# How to force narrator to read without focus change?

Tags: focus, accessibility, narrator

I have an input box. Based on UP and DOWN arrow keypress, I want narrator to read values from a list which is a sibling element of this input box, i.e. on pressing DOWN, the narrator should read the next element from the list and vice versa (note that the actual focus always remains on the input box). What is a good way of doing this?
Please comment if you need more info regarding the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out how to fix this. Use **aria-activedescendant** on the input field  for the id of the selected list item, and the narrator will know the intended focused element and will read out its content.

According to w3 [wiki](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-activedescendant_to_allow_changes_in_focus_within_widgets_to_be_communicated_to_Assistive_Technology): "The aria-activedescendant attribute is generally used in composite widgets where a container element is focusable, and its child elements are not natively focusable. In such cases, this attribute replaces the need for focusable child elements within the container by notifying the user agent of the current active child element within the widget."

Here is a [working example](http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/11/) of this scenario.